# Cambiar formato de un número en php

Tags: php

Quisiera que un número equivalente a 10,000.00 sea 10.000,00, mi código es el siguiente:

```
$ventaspre = number_format($ventaspre);
echo $ventaspre . "\r\n"
```

Obtengo el siguiente error: A non well formed numeric value encountered.
Además lo que quiero obtener es que mi número 10,000.00 sea 10.000,00 pero no sé como convertirlo.

Comment: Antes de aplicar el formato coloca una línea con `var_dump($ventaspre);`, probablemente ya viene con algún formato y es lo que ocasiona el mensaje de error.

Answer (score 0):

Este código debería conseguir lo que necesitas. Al final es un string al cual le cambias los '.' por un carácter auxiliar, para luego poder localizarlos nuevamente y reemplazarlos por el caracter deseado:

```
<?php
    $ventaspre = "10,000.00";
    $ventaspre = floatval(str_replace(',', '', $ventaspre));

    echo (36.92/$ventaspre) . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Hola obtengo este resultado: 10,000,00 lo que deseo luego de la conversión es poder dividir ese valor: Ejemplo: 36.92 / 10.000.00 => de esa forma necesito la división porque si no es así la división no sale como deseo

Comment: Entonces lo que necesitas es eliminar las comas ya que el decimal correcto en php es el punto. Posteriormente, parseas el valor a float y ya lo tienes listo para dividir. Código editado! Espero te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

ahí estuve probando tu código y de esta manera debería funcionar. Yo lo probé con un numero 'N', vos utiliza lo que necesites de allí. Uso un str_replace para sacarle la ',' al numero y luego le doy formato con la función 'number_format' Saludos.

```
$var = '12,000.33';
$number = (string)$var;
$num = str_replace(',','',$number);
$num = number_format($num,2,",",".");
echo $num
```